# rename a group_by statement using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I would like to rename the column created using group_by in dplyr. The name created is `format(date2, "%Y-%m")`,not very helpful. I have tried several things. I would like the new name to be "yrMth"

```
    df <- data.frame(Person = c(rep("abc",3), rep("eee", 5)),
             date = c("4/1/2016", "4/3/2016", "4/12/2016", "5/3/2016", "5/4/2016","5/10/2016","5/6/2016", "5/11/2016"),
             account = c("123","123","123","222","222","333","222","333"), stringsAsFactors = F)

    df$date2 <- mdy(df$date)

    df %>%
      group_by(format(date2, "%Y-%m"))

  Person      date account      date2 `format(date2, "%Y-%m")`
   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <date>                    <chr>
1    abc  4/1/2016     123 2016-04-01                  2016-04
2    abc  4/3/2016     123 2016-04-03                  2016-04
3    abc 4/12/2016     123 2016-04-12                  2016-04
4    eee  5/3/2016     222 2016-05-03                  2016-05
5    eee  5/4/2016     222 2016-05-04                  2016-05
6    eee 5/10/2016     333 2016-05-10                  2016-05
7    eee  5/6/2016     222 2016-05-06                  2016-05
8    eee 5/11/2016     333 2016-05-11                  2016-05
```

The following code does not work, any ideas.

```
    df %>%
      mutate( yrMth = group_by(format(date2, "%Y-%m")))

    df %>%
      rename( yrMth = group_by(format(date2, "%Y-%m")))
```

Comment: Not a big dplyr expert, but couldn't you just mutate first and then group - `df %>% mutate(yrMth=format(date2, "%Y-%m")) %>% group_by(yrMth)` ? I'll wait and see if some dplyr whiz can show a better way.

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do: `df %>%
  group_by(yrMth=format(date2, "%Y-%m"))`. That actually gives the same result as `df %>% mutate(yrMth=format(date2, "%Y-%m"))`, except that in the former case the data frame also has the grouping attribute. But why not just format the date the way you want when you first create `date2`?

Answer (score 7):

No need to use `mutate` or `rename`. As was stated by eipi10´s comment, this is easily achieved by simply doing this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(yrMth = format(date2, "%Y-%m"))
```

If you were to name the variable dynamically, this would be an option:

```
name <- "yrMth2"

df %>% 
  group_by(!!name := get(format(date2, "%Y-%m")) )
```

Answer (score 1):

`df<- group_by(df, date2) %>% mutate(yrMth = format(date2, "%Y-%m"))`

This works perfectly fine for me

But if you want to do this without creating any new column, you can use following function:

```
df<- mutate_at(df, vars(date), function(x){x =  format(x, "%Y-%m"); return(x)})
```

Comment: There's no need for the grouping step if you just want to add  the `yrMth` column.

Comment: Agreed. I did this just to replicate what user is doing.

Comment: I know I can add a new column to the df dataframe. I was trying to do this without creating the new column, like summarize in dplyr.

Comment: Ohh got it. You can do that using `mutate_at`. I have added the code in the answer. Let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late, but in `dplyr_1.0.2`, you can simply set the name of your grouping variable name when you call `group_by`:

```r
df <- data.frame(Person = c(rep("abc",3), rep("eee", 5)),
             date = c("4/1/2016", "4/3/2016", "4/12/2016", "5/3/2016", "5/4/2016","5/10/2016","5/6/2016", "5/11/2016"),
             account = c("123","123","123","222","222","333","222","333"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$date2 <- mdy(df$date)
df %>% group_by("yrMth" = format(date2, "%Y-%m"))
```